# Proof that $\forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\ \sum\limits_1^\infty P(|X_n-x|>\epsilon)<\infty\implies X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} x$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Although replated to probability theory, this statement seemed completely of real analysis to me.

I am trying to prove that if $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables and $X$ is another random variable such that

> $\forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\ \sum\limits_1^\infty P(|X_n-x|>\epsilon)<\infty\implies X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} x$

My proof:

> $$\forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\  \sum\limits_1^\infty P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\infty\\\implies  \forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\  P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0\ \ \cdots\cdots(Borel-Cantelli)\\\implies \forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\ P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon \text{ for infinitely many } n )=0\\\implies P(X_n\to X \text{ as } n\to\infty)=1\\\implies X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$$

Is everything rigorously correct? Especially can I put a ***double equivalence*** sign in going from the second to the third line?

Comment: I think that, especially if you are writing for an introductory probability class, your first and second-to-last steps both deserve some expansion. In particular in the first step you should be explaining how you're going from limsups of *sets* to limsups of *functions*, and in the second-to-last step you should carefully explain why you can take the $\epsilon$ to be rational. (Just in general this would probably be better to write out in terms of unions and intersections.)

Comment: Re the equivalence you are asking about:$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n>\epsilon\implies\#\{n\mid a_n>\epsilon\}=+\infty\implies\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\geqslant\epsilon$$

Comment: A factual remark: you now have posted half a dozen questions on the very same topic (almost sure convergence and limsups of random variables), some of them with detailed answers, but the stream of posts continues... Does it mean that you understood none of the explanations you received? Then it might be time to select a specific, extra localized, point, and to try to fully understand it, or we are going to continue the series of questions ad infinitum, with no visible progress.

Comment: @Ian I think the first step is the definition of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, and we are directly allowed to use it. But I agree that the second-last step requires a proof. In that direction, I am using the proof [given in pt. number $21$ here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Convergence.html) .

Comment: @Ian However , I have a small (extremely insignificant and silly looking) doubt. The above link says claims that _By **Boole's inequality**, a countable union of events has probability_ $0$ _if and only if every event in the union has probability_ $0$. My question is : What has $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)=0\implies P(A_i)=0 $ to do with _Boole's  inequality_ ? Isn't the trivial fact that for any $k\in \Bbb{N} \ ,\ P(A_k)\leqslant P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$ sufficient to prove the claim?

Comment: That one seems like overkill, it seems rather trivial indeed.

Comment: Anyway, to me that Borel-Cantelli step is not the definition of either Borel-Cantelli Lemma. To me you should rewrite everything in terms of events instead.

Comment: @Ian I mean, the **onlyif** part is okay with Boole's inequality; has Boole's inequality to do anything with the **if** part?

Comment: @Ian I am laughing at myself now for posting such a trivial question here..:-D

Comment: Boole's inequality *is* that trivial inequality.

Comment: @Ian I don't want to extend this useless chat, but I think Boole's inequality is $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$

Comment: Eh fair...anyway the name is not really so important.